# SQLite select query with Integer Binding in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to execute the following sqlite statement inside my android app:

> String sql = "SELECT ID, lt, lg FROM Location WHERE ABS(lt-?) <= ? AND
>   ABS(lg-?) <= ?";

I have tried using 'rawQuery' in the following sql statement:

```
String sql = "SELECT ID, lt, lg FROM Location WHERE ABS(lt-" + lt + ") <= " + ltGridLen  + " AND ABS(lg-" + lg + ") <= " + lgGridLen + " LIMIT 1";
```

which worked. However, I want to know whether there is any other more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rawQuery` accepts parameters to bind, but only as an array of `String`s.
Comparing an integer against a string will not work correctly.

With integers, there are no problems with formatting or SQL injection, so you do not need to use parameters for them.